# What is the meaning of "To get things done"?

Tags: meaning

I listened to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFsFZwpB-tE) in which the woman is saying in 0:53 minutes:

> "...because she is a progressive who **get things done**".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The locution

**get {something} {past participle}**

get the door painted

get the claim processed

get his eyes examined

means to cause the {something} to become {painted, processed, examined, etc}

"Things" means loosely "items on an agenda".

She causes things on an agenda to become "done", that is, to become "accomplished" or "finished".

She accomplishes things.

If you *don't* get things done, you are said to be "ineffectual".

Someone who gets things done is "effective".

Answer (score 0):

'Get it done' means 'finish the task on time'. But it conveys rather more than that, as described [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100448/what-is-the-meaning-of-get-it-done) at StackExchange.

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! Please [edit] your answer to provide some references (e.g. a dictionary entry); your answer has been flagged as low quality by the system.