# What is the meaning of get it done?

Tags: causative-get

I often get confused with this phrase "Get It Done" . I searched a lot on the internet about this. But where does it actually use ?

Word "Get" is also used when you arrange for another person to do some work. eg.
"I ll get my hair cut" (Means i ll arrange for barber to cut my hairs)

But i am confused with the following part-

But i have heard my manager saying this word 100 times, We ll get it done. He simply mean we will do it. so can get it done replace the word do it ? if yes when do we have this replacement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a business/office environment "We'll get it done." is more than just accepting the task. It is also connotes, "We won't fail to accomplish this task satisfactorily."

A manager telling an employee to "get it done" often implies either that the employee's current progress towards completion is unsatisfactory or that there is now an urgency to the task's completion. It could be both at the same time.

I would not replace "do it" with "get it done". This is not because your meaning would be confused but because the latter seems harsher. From a manager, the phrase "We have this important client project that I need you to do." is more polite than "We have this important client project. I need you to get it done."

Answer (score 0):

"get it done " means to imply a lot of efforts for any work.It show the urgency to complete any work without delay.It also show our confidence towards any specific action.