# Does the phrase "to get something done" have different meanings?

Tags: phrase-meaning

https://www.tofluency.com/english-phrase-have-get-something-done/

*To have / get something done means that someone does something for you.
...
Here are more examples:
“I need to get my hair cut soon.”
...*

**I can understand what the above text means. but there are somethings like:**

https://www.wikihow.com/Get-Things-Done

*Have you ever wanted to get something done but you can't seem to finish? Maybe you just have a lack of motivation, or maybe distractions are getting the better of you.*

**I guess in the above context "to get something done" has a different meaning. Am I right or not?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "To get things done"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81873/what-is-the-meaning-of-to-get-things-done)

Comment: "To get something done" does not necessarily mean that someone else does something for you. _I'll get the dishes done tonight_ does not mean: I will get someone to wash them, although, you could. I suppose it's an idiomatic way of saying I'll wash the dishes (by whatever means necessary). But to have something done means what you said.